# PHP Associate Array from POST

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the following array built from some POST data, I grabbed this via print_r

```
print_r($_POST['options']);
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        ['member_id'] => 6 
        ['leadership_id'] => 0 ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        ['member_id'] => 7 
        ['leadership_id'] => 1 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        ['member_id'] => 2 
        ['leadership_id'] => 2 ) )
```

That seems correct to me, but if I try to look through it in a foreach:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $test) {
    echo $test['member_id'];
    echo $test['leadership_id'];
}
```

This just gives me back the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: member_id
Notice: Undefined index: leadership_id
```

It seems to send that error each time it would be going through the loop, so it's obviously not being referenced correctly.

I would think the foreach would make $test loop through it as $test[0]['member_id'], but that seems to be incorrect by how it's responding.

Got it working as something that was said made me think of experimenting with another loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $tmp) {
    foreach ($tmp AS $opt) {
        echo $opt['member_id'];
        echo $opt['leadership_id'];
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the first foreach only saw one array, so the second finds the rest, though when I print out the variables it looks odd:

```
Member ID: 6
Leadership_ID: 6
Member ID: 0
Leadership_ID: 0
Member ID: 7
Leadership_ID: 7
Member ID: 1
Leadership_ID: 1
Member ID: 2
Leadership_ID: 2
Member ID: 2
Leadership_ID: 2
```

It semes it may be an issue with how the HTML is loading the data, here is an example:

```
<input type="hidden" name="options[0]['member_id']" value="6">Name
<select name="options[0]['leadership_id']">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">Small Unit</option>
    <option value="2">Large Unit</option>
</select><br />

<input type="hidden" name="options[1]['member_id']" value="7">Pyras
<select name="options[1]['leadership_id']">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">Small Unit</option>
    <option value="2">Large Unit</option>
</select><br />
```

Comment: try as foreach ($_POST['options'] as $key=>$test)

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: It should check my answer I have created an example as yours

Comment: it works here with the exact same data structure with yours. Do you print the $_POST['options'] to test it just before the iteration so you are definitely sure about the incoming data ?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that the error occurs when the data is missing. Put a check for `isset()`.

Comment: Yeah, print_r is right before I loop through it. I'm eventually passing them into a function, but this is just trying to figure out why it was failing. That'd odd if it's working on your end.

Comment: Please let us know what worked in the end when you find a solution. That's a strange problem.

Comment: I acutally got it to work by putting it in another foreach.

   foreach ($_POST['options'] as $tmp) {
    foreach ($tmp AS $opt) {
     echo $opt['member_id'];
     echo $opt['leadership_id'];
    }
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get with this code:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $test) {
    print_r($test);
}
```

Post all content.

**EDIT 1**: Try this:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $test) {
    if (isset($test['member_id']) && isset($test['leadership_id'])) {
        var_dump($test['member_id']);
        var_dump($test['leadership_id']);
    } else {
        echo 'Bad Values:' . var_dump($test);
    }
}
```

What do you get for that?

**EDIT 2**:
It seems like your keys have extra ' in them. What is your HTML? If that is not an option do:

```
foreach ($_POST['options'] as $test) {
    if (isset($test["'member_id'"]) && isset($test["'leadership_id'"])) {
        var_dump($test["'member_id'"]);
        var_dump($test["'leadership_id'"]);
    } else {
        echo 'Bad Values:' . var_dump($test);
    }
}
```

**Edit 3**:

Change your HTML to:

```
<input type="hidden" name="options[0][member_id]" value="6">Name
<select name="options[0][leadership_id]">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">Small Unit</option>
    <option value="2">Large Unit</option>
</select><br />

<input type="hidden" name="options[1][member_id]" value="7">Pyras
<select name="options[1][leadership_id]">
    <option value="0">None</option>
    <option value="1">Small Unit</option>
    <option value="2">Large Unit</option>
</select><br />
```

Comment: Running that gives this result:

Array ( ['member_id'] => 6 ['leadership_id'] => 0 ) Array ( ['member_id'] => 7 ['leadership_id'] => 1 ) Array ( ['member_id'] => 2 ['leadership_id'] => 2 )

Comment: The update is giving me Array ( ['member_id'] => 6 ['leadership_id'] => 0 ) Bad Values:1Array ( ['member_id'] => 7 ['leadership_id'] => 1 ) Bad Values:1Array ( ['member_id'] => 2 ['leadership_id'] => 2 ) Bad Values:1


The weird part of that is that the values should always be set as they're coming from a form with only a hidden field and a select so there is no way data could not be there.

Comment: @DarkSnake Can you try it again with var_dump, I suspect the keys aren't correctly set.

Comment: First is the base second after foreacch
Level 1: array(3) { [0]=> array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "6" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "7" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "0" } [2]=> array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "2" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "2" } } 

Level 2: array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "6" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "0" } 

Level 2: array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "7" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "0" } 

Level 2: array(2) { ["'member_id'"]=> string(1) "2" ["'leadership_id'"]=> string(1) "2" }

Comment: Your keys are 'member_id' and not member_id, you have an extra ' you need to account for. What is your HTML like?

Comment: Hmm, it's like this:

<input type="hidden" name="options[0]['member_id']" value="6">Name
        <select name="options[0]['leadership_id']">

With a counter to increase the array. I've also tried it without the  counter and it didn't seem to work either way. Without it, it seems to only get one row.

Comment: and the result of your edit is:
string(1) "6" string(1) "0" string(1) "7" string(1) "1" string(1) "2" string(1) "2"

Comment: Ah crap, I think you may have found it. I did put an extra ' in my thing. I've been referencing the arrays in that format so much I did it in the HTML too. I fixed that but it doesn't seem to have fixed the base issue.

Comment: Yes, if in your HTML you do name="options[1][member_id]" and name="options[1][leadership_id]" then you would be able to access them without the extra '.

Comment: Yeah, it's working now. I was able to take it back to one foreach look and I can see them fine now. I hate dumb oversights, ha. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to access it like this:
foreach($options as $key=>$opt){
  echo $opt["member_id"];
  echo $opt["leadership_id"];
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between this and op's original code? The $key is omitted by op as its not used.

Comment: The difference is that if your array was a single level array that means: array('member_id'=>'test','leadership_id'=>'test2'); your code would work perfectly.  But since what you have is  an array of arrays, you need to loop through the arrays in the second level.

Comment: While that didn't fix it, it did lead me to finding a way to make it work. That got me thinking and I added another foreach into the loop and it seems to work fine now.

   foreach ($_POST['options'] as $tmp) {
    foreach ($tmp AS $opt) {
     echo $opt['member_id'];
     echo $opt['leadership_id'];
    }
   }

Comment: @user2411276 See the docs at - http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php. The differnce between the two foreach is simply that one is key,value pair while the other is simply value.

Comment: Try this:
$myar = array (
  array (
    'member_id' => 6,
    'leadership_id' => 0 ),
  array (
    'member_id' => 7,
    'leadership_id' =>1)
  ) ;


echo "<pre>";
foreach($myar as $k=>$v){
 print_r($v['member_id']);
}

echo "</pre>";
The code i gave you works, it is just another way of the accessing the data.  you could do it the key=>value way or put another loop to access the array values, it is upto you.  But the code I gave you should also fetch the same result.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, so it's another issue.

Here's a working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf657dd63428e5199ddd22c643fa464c0657b43f

Maybe context will help us solve the problem.